# Query Optimization with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    PE1.PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY, -- primary key
    PE1.Customer_Ban, 
    PE1.Subscriber_No, 
    PE1.Prod_Equip_Cd, 
    PE1.Prod_Equip_Txt, 
    PE1.Prod_Equip_Category_Txt--,
    -- PE2.ep_rnk ------------------ UNCOMMENT THIS LINE
FROM 
    INT_ADM.Product_Equipment_Dim PE1
    INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Ban, Subscriber_No ORDER BY Start_Dt ASC) AS ep_rnk
            FROM INT_ADM.Product_Equipment_Dim PE2
    ) PE2
    ON PE2.PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY = PE1.PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY
WHERE 
    Line_Of_Business_Cd = 'M' 
    AND /*v_Date_Start*/ TO_DATE( '2022/01/12', 'yyyy/mm/dd' ) BETWEEN Start_Dt AND End_Dt 
    AND Current_Ind = 'Y'
```

If I run it as you see it then it runs in under a second.

If I run it with `-- PE2.ep_rnk ------------------ UNCOMMENT THIS LINE` uncommented then the query takes up to 5 minutes to complete.

I know it's something to do with ROW_NUMBER() but after looking all over online I can't find a good explanation and solution. Does anyone know why uncommenting that line makes the query so slow, and what I can do about it so it runs fast?

Much appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: That subquery forces an expensive calculation of a row number for *every* row in the table, temporarily caching the response, then an expensive join with a subset of the data. Is that what you really want?  Do you need to calculate the row number *before* filtering? Otherwise you can replace the commented line with the `ROW_NUMBER` expression

Comment: If you comment that line the entire subquery is ignored because it doesn't affect the result - the subquery performs a self join on the PK, which won't filter any row

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? You could replace the self join with a CTE or nested query that returns all necessary fields *and the row number, and use the outer query to filter the results. The query engine may be doing this already though

Comment: Important to know - how many rows (compared to the total rows) return the query. Also please learn how can you check (and post) the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) of both queries.

Answer (score 1):

The *root cause* is, that even if the predicate in the `where` clause allows an efficient access to the rows of the table (but I suspect your *below a second* response is the time to get the first page of the result), you need in the subquery to access *all rows* of the table, to *window sort* them and finaly to join them to the first row source.

So if you comment out the `ep_rnk` Oracle is *smart enought* that it *do not need to evaluate the subquery* at all, because the subquery is on the *same table* and the join is on the *primary key* - so no row can be lost or duplicated in the join.

What can you improve?

Not much. If the  `WHERE` condition filters the table very restrictive (and you end with only a small number of `PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY`) make the same filer in the subquery:

```
( 
    SELECT 
        PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Ban, Subscriber_No ORDER BY Start_Dt ASC) AS ep_rnk
        FROM INT_ADM.Product_Equipment_Dim PE2
        --- filer added
        WHERE PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY in (
            SELECT PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY
            FROM INT_ADM.Product_Equipment_Dim
            WHERE ... same predicate as in the main query ...
        )
) PE2
```

If the predicate returns all (or most) of the `PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY` the only (often used) way is to *pre-calculate* the rank e.g. in a materialized view

The `materialized view` is defined as follows

```
SELECT 
    PE1.PRODUCT_EQUIPMENT_KEY, -- primary key
    PE1.Customer_Ban, 
    PE1.Subscriber_No, 
    PE1.Prod_Equip_Cd, 
    PE1.Prod_Equip_Txt, 
    PE1.Prod_Equip_Category_Txt--,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_Ban, Subscriber_No ORDER BY Start_Dt ASC) AS ep_rnk
FROM 
    INT_ADM.Product_Equipment_Dim PE1
```

and you simple query from it - without a join.